# How to reuse install options?

Tags: system-installation

Is there a way to save options I have used to install ubuntu server
so next time I will use them and do not answer master questions again?

Comment: Yes. Look into [preseeding](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/amd64/apbs02.html).

Comment: It ask anyway user fullname/username/password/diskpartitioning/proxy/automatic updates/software to install

Comment: Then you must have done something wrong. I use preseeding and aside from the initial language selection options (which I disabled using boot parameters), I don't get asked anything.

Comment: I did some tests, when I even write wrong url=http://preceed I warned about that only after keyboard layout detection. [here](http://searchitchannel.techtarget.com/feature/Performing-an-automated-Ubuntu-install-using-preseeding) " Unfortunately we will need to specify a few extra options on the command line so the installer can get past the initial phase of the install". How you disable any question? may you give me a link, please.